# windbg: can I trust parameters in the call stack when it says the following frames may be wrong?

Tags: pointers, windbg, heap-corruption

Our C++ software is crashing with either an access violation or a heap corruption (according to windbg).  So, we've enabled the standard page heap and now we're analyzing the dumps.  Our software writes out a minidump during an unhandled exception.  I look at it in windbg and the call stack looks fairly reasonable.  I have the symbols for our code and Windows, but not the Oracle code in between.  My question is: can I really believe the parameters displayed in the `kv` call when in the stack I get the message: "WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong."?  Here's the stack after doing the `.ecxr` and `kv`:

```
# ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
00 06f6ed20 7c863879 017c1000 06f6edd0 06f6edac ntdll!DbgBreakPoint (FPO: [0,0,0])
01 06f6ed30 7c8785ee 0000000e 7c8788ac 017c1000 ntdll!RtlpPageHeapStop+0x72 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
02 06f6edac 7c878cec 017c1000 00000009 1214d208 ntdll!RtlpDphReportCorruptedBlock+0x154 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
03 06f6ee10 7c879874 1e456fb0 00000000 04011000 ntdll!RtlpDphAddToDelayedFreeQueue+0x120 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
04 06f6ee34 7c879a94 04011000 04110000 01001002 ntdll!RtlpDphNormalHeapFree+0x73 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
05 06f6ee8c 7c87c96b 04010000 01001002 1e456fd0 ntdll!RtlpDebugPageHeapFree+0x146 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
06 06f6eef4 7c85560a 04010000 01001002 1e456fd0 ntdll!RtlDebugFreeHeap+0x2c (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
07 06f6efcc 7c83e330 04010000 01001002 1e456fd0 ntdll!RtlFreeHeapSlowly+0x37 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
08 06f6f0b0 7c34218a 04010000 01001002 1e456fd0 ntdll!RtlFreeHeap+0x11a (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for sqora32.dll
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for sqora32.dll - 
09 06f6f0f8 03f6dffc 1e456fd0 06f6f11c 03f67589 msvcr71!free+0xc3 (FPO: [Non-Fpo]) (CONV: cdecl) [f:\vs70builds\3052\vc\crtbld\crt\src\free.c @ 103]
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
0a 06f6f104 03f67589 1e456fd8 1dbed030 04833aa0 sqora32!SQLTablesW+0x434a0
0b 06f6f11c 03f5f010 04e209f8 1d879540 03f7a40c sqora32!SQLTablesW+0x3ca2d
0c 06f6f144 03f5eb44 04e209f8 1d879540 1dbed030 sqora32!SQLTablesW+0x344b4
0d 06f6f17c 03f481c8 04e209f8 000000d5 1d879540 sqora32!SQLTablesW+0x33fe8
0e 06f6f1b4 03f28522 04e209f8 1d879540 04833aa0 sqora32!SQLTablesW+0x1d66c
0f 06f6f1f0 03f24d80 04e209f8 02dd54f0 000000d5 sqora32!SQLPrepareW+0x37a
10 06f6f21c 4bf767f3 04e209f8 02dd54f0 000000d5 sqora32!SQLExecDirectW+0xa8
11 06f6f23c 4bf9464a 02dd54f0 000000d5 00000001 odbc32!SQLExecute+0x26f (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
12 06f6f260 4c631cff 4bfa0000 1225c3c0 000000d5 odbc32!SQLExecDirect+0x77 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
13 06f6f278 4c6367a5 02dd99b0 1225c3c0 000000d5 odbccr32!CurSQLExecDirect+0x1e (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
14 06f6f29c 4c63549b 12256338 4c631ce1 02dd73f8 odbccr32!CSql::SubmitSql+0x161 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
15 06f6f2d4 4c63774a 12256338 1697d508 000000d5 odbccr32!CSql::ExecDirect+0x43 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
16 06f6f314 4bf767f3 02dd99b0 1697d508 000000d5 odbccr32!CLExecDirect+0x6a (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
17 06f6f334 4bf9464a 1697d508 000000d5 00000000 odbc32!SQLExecute+0x26f (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
18 06f6f358 01711385 4bfa0000 1697d508 000000d5 odbc32!SQLExecDirect+0x77 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
19 06f6f380 01746a82 1697d508 00000001 06f6f6a0 odbcwrap!ODBCProcessSQLv+0x365 (FPO: [Uses EBP] [4,2,4])
1a 06f6fea8 01742474 1478d678 16604288 01540000 TransLog!DBInsertLogRecord+0x312 (FPO: [Uses EBP] [2,705,4])
1b 06f6fed4 003dbf7c 000000a8 003daf77 01540000 TransLog!LogManager::Run+0x204
```

The parameters to our function `odbcwrap!ODBCProcessSQLv are: 1697d508 00000001 06f6f6a0`

- 2nd param = `00000001` - statement handle - which is correct
- 3rd param = `06f6f6a0` - is the SQL string - which is correct
- 1st param = `1697d508`.  This SHOULD be a pointer to our ODBC class.  But instead this pointer is another SQL string!!

This is very odd for a few reasons.  If this really were the value passed into ODBCProcessSQLv our code would have blown up inside ODBCProcessSQLv long before going down into Oracle.  So, then I'm thinking the ODBC class was fine coming in but we overwrote it at some point after calling down into Oracle.  That would mean we're overwriting the stack, right?  This is entirely possible but I’m having difficulty proving it.

But I'm still curious to find out if I can trust this `1697d508` value on the stack, considering the message above this in the stack saying the following frames may be wrong.

Another odd thing is the SQLExecDirect call:

`18 06f6f358 01711385 4bfa0000 1697d508 000000d5 odbc32!SQLExecDirect+0x77 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])`

You can see that same `1697d508` is passed as the 2nd parameter - which is the correct SQL string and `000000d5` is the length of this string - which is also correct.  But `4bfa0000` doesn't seem to make sense.  This parameter should be `02dd99b0` - which is the statement handle.  I know this because the ODBC class pointer looks OK when passed into `TransLog!DBInsertLogRecord` - which is `1478d678` (param #1).  So, when I look at `1478d678` this is the ODBC class pointer object and I can see that the statement handle should be `02dd99b0`.  Why is it this `4bfa0000`?  Again, is it that we're corrupting the stack?  What's also interesting, is looking up the stack, just 2 frames, I see that `02dd99b0` passed into CLExecDirect!!

```
16 06f6f314 4bf767f3 02dd99b0 1697d508 000000d5 odbccr32!CLExecDirect+0x6a (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
```

So, it does appear that we're passing that `02dd99b0` value in but for some reason either windbg is not able to get accurate info or we're corrupting the stack.

This is really pointing to a corrupted stack, right?  How can this happen?  Can you give me an example?  If it's corrupted, why is it only the first parameter that's wrong to SQLExecDirect and ODBCProcessSQLv, but the other parameters are OK?

Any help is greatly appreciated...

Comment: when symbols are wrong there is a very high chance that the parameters are also incorrect als o notice the offsets  like name+0xveryhugeoffset this indicates it might simply be wrong do not trust them unless you break there physically in your src code and check   set a breakpoint on a known function in your code i assume translog!dbxxxx and step in into the oracle code run  since you have the stacktrace try setting breakpoints on oracle code i think i can trust only upto sqora32!SQLPrepareW+0x37a where the offset seems to be reasonable

Comment: For debug build, you can pretty much trust the parameter shown on WinDbg (only apply to debug build modules). For release build, due to various compiler optimizations, parameters' memory locations are often reused. So  never trust the callstack without back tracing the caller assembly.  So when in doubt, reproduce the dump with debug build.

Comment: If anyone with missing symbols (sqora32 in your case) has FPO optimizations, stack trace generation is indeed unreliable and debugger dutifully informs you of that.

Comment: as for the arguments, unless they *are* on the stack, debugger doesn't know how to extract them. They may very well be in registers... which you can find by examining the disassembly...

ub TransLog!DBInsertLogRecord+0x312 will show is actually being put on the stack. Probably the first parameter is in ECX -- so you then can examine disassembly of odbcwrap!ODBCProcessSQLv to see what does it do with ECX...

Comment: @printf fan - Did you enable gflags to target the cause of the heap corruption and get a dump with gflags enabled? If not, I would recommend doing so - as the offending callstack with gflags enabled will likely be different.

Answer (score 0):

The top frames with symbols should be OK, but frames in dll’s without symbols can’t be trusted.
However my experience is that further down when symbols again are OK, the prams are correct.
Some thoughts:
In frame 8, the first param 04010000 should be the heap handle, the next the address to free.Try to take a

```
!heap –p –a 01001002  and see if it is a valid handle & address.
```

The address 
looks wrong as it is not aligned.
Try also an

```
!address 1e456fd0 from frame 9 first param.
```

This param is probably wrong, as it should be eq the second param from frame 8.

Comment: Tried to put in whole windbg output but SO prevents me... 
!heap returned nothing.  Tried !address and didn't see much. Did `dc 1e456fd0-20` and see the expected: 

`1e456fb0  abcdaaa9 84011000 00020008 00020030  ............0...

1e456fc0  002808a0 1b3cbde8 005f4748 dcbaaaa9  ..(...<.HG_.....

1e456fd0  f0f0f0f0 f0f0f0f0 f0f0f0f0 f0f0f0f0  ................`

Showing this is a freed block. Ran `dds 005f4748` (to see the call stack of the free action) and see the same call stack as shown above.  Huh?

Comment: Another question: if I run dds on a call stack value in this page heap block, I often get several call stacks.  Which is the correct one?  Why do I get multiple ones?  Usually the first one makes the most sense but the others are confusing